# Perl Script in PHP

Tags: php, perl

I have a perl script, which takes a query string parameter, connects to a database and displays data.

I'd like to include that script in a PHP file like so:

```
include('perlscript.pl?item=302');
```

Such that the perl script's response is displayed on the PHP/HTML page.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With backticks?

```
echo `/path/to/perl perlscript.pl item=302`
```

Comment: If the `302` is coming from the query, this may leave you wide open to shell injection!  Unfortunately PHP has no safe execution mechanism; you'll have to `escapeshellarg` manually.

Answer (score 0):

If safe_mode is on or shell_exec is disabled, one option is to fetch the content of your script using fopen() or using curl.