# How to launch PHP from Perl?

Tags: php, perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I invoke a PHP script from Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508445/how-can-i-invoke-a-php-script-from-perl)

I was using a PHP-script to output different text depending on the URL parameters passed to it. After that it was received by a special program. Now I'm writing a Perl-script, inside of which I should be able to receive the same text depending on the same parameters.

How can I do it using the existing PHP-script (i.e. copy PHP output to a variable inside of a Perl program)?  I found an [article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9282?page=0,0) about integrating this languages, but it is using a special module [PHP::Interpreter](http://search.cpan.org/~aff/PHP-Interpreter-1.0.2/lib/PHP/Interpreter.pm). Is there an easier (embedded) way to do it?  Thank you.

Comment: Indeed, backticks are often sufficient. You must use the `php-cgi` interpreter however, not the commandline version. Then the inherited environment variables (SERVER_GATEWAY, QUERY_STRING, ...) will allow the PHP script to operate unchanged to produce the output.

Comment: @eugene y, sorry, didn't notice that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments above you want to execute PHP script on remote server.
I assume, PHP script is available through the web at some location, for example 'http://phpserver.com/yourscript.php'.

Then you can execute your PHP script on remote server using [LWP](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP) package:

```
use LWP::Simple;
my $response = get("http://phpserver.com/yourscript.php");
print $response;
```

Comment: it worked, thanks a lot! It is already great, but couldn't you tell me, is [LWP](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.03/lib/LWP.pm) module preinstalled with Perl?

Comment: It's not a [CORE](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-modules-L.html) module but it's installed on most web-hostings. Depending on your system you can install it using `apt-get install libwww-perl` or `cpan LWP`

Comment: this script should also be used by my colleagues (on other machines) and downloading and installing additional module will be yet another condition for them. But for now I see that yours is the best solution. Thank a lot!

Comment: You also may consider receiving response using wget or curl command, depends on which is available on your systems. replace `get(...)` with `\`curl '$url'\`` or `\`wget -qO- '$url'\``

Answer (score 1):

You can execute any external command using backticks (``) and store the resulting output in a variable. In your case, something like this should work:

```
$result = `php myscript.php`;
```

The output is now in the scalar `$result`.

Comment: thank you, but won't there be a problem, as my Perl-script's working directory is on my local machine, and the PHP-script should be executed on the remote server?

Comment: As I expected, I get "'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." in STDERR when trying this solution.

Comment: Naturally, you must consider the full path to your php binary (assuming you're executing locally). So for additional clarity, I suppose I could have written it as:

$result = `/path/to/php myscript.php`;

Since you've now indicated you wish to execute it on a remote server, then something like yko's solution should work for you.